# Adding commands for discord bot in replit

Tags: python, pycharm, replit

Only a quick simple question. Just coded my discord bot using pycharm. Followed a video on it and got it now running 24/7. However.. my question is if I want to add, replace, or remove a command do I have to use both replit and pycharm when adding removing or replacing a command or can I just stick to using replit?

Comment: If you are hosting on replit use replit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just edit .py file on replit and reboot the bot to have it applied.